# How to check whether table is busy or free before running the ALTER or creating TRIGGER on that table

Tags: postgresql, triggers, ddl, postgresql-9.2

We have thousands of tables. Out of these tables we have few tables. Which are busy some times. If I execute any ALTER statement or creating trigger on those tables I am unable to do it. How to check whether table is busy or free before running the ALTER or creating TRIGGER on that table in postgresql database.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to run

```
LOCK TABLE mytable NOWAIT;
```

If you get no error, the `ALTER TABLE` statement can proceed without waiting.

Answer (score 1):

Query below returns locked objects in a database.

```
select t.relname, l.locktype, page, virtualtransaction, pid, mode, granted 
  from pg_locks l, pg_stat_all_tables t 
 where l.relation=t.relid 
 order by relation asc;
```

Comment: Perhaps, but what if somebody locks the table between that statement and your attempt to `ALTER TABLE`?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s I don't like JOIN syntax style. For me personally, it is less readable that is why I use the old style. Of course, most prefer JOIN style and are happy with it. 
I prefer to have all my tables in one place then looking for them in all query.